# Angular application is running but not loading on browser?

Tags: angular

I have a problem in my angular application.
While application is running without any problem but when loading in browser.

The Browser saying that 'This Page Having a Problem'

Pictures:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does this behavior persists while using another port? Windows sometimes can be tricky with its applications (especially apps like Skype), and even if Angular CLI now tracks if port is available sometimes it's not working properly. Can you try other port? Some big one, like 8080.

Comment: look at the javascript console log and post more details

Comment: Did you stop and start the application i.e., ng serve command again like few times?

Answer (score -1):

You have a `stackoverflow` exception which is caused by your application. Fix it.